# How to get updated feed come on the top and also who feed get comment come at the top in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I am create one store procedure for the list of feed. i want to feed on updated datetime based on the top of the tab and then after who feed get a comment that commented feed comes of the top and one step less updated feed. so now 1st feed is commented feed and 2nd is updated feed like this i want to feed list.so i am write this query but not get expected list for feed.

This is my query =>

```
SELECT Tab.* FROM (
       SELECT 
       C.CaseId,                                 
        ISNULL((SELECT TOP(1)InsertDateTime FROM CaseComment WHERE CaseId = C.CaseId ORDER BY InsertDateTime DESC),getDate()) AS CommentInsertDateTime,
         row_number() over (partition by C.CaseId order by CC.InsertDateTime desc) as RawNumber,
       CC.InsertDateTime as CommentInsertDate,
       C.UpdateDateTime 
    FROM Case C     
    LEFT join CaseComment CC ON CC.CaseId = C.CaseId        
    WHERE C.IsApproved = 1
        AND C.IsDeleted = 0 ) Tab where RawNumber = 1 AND ORDER BY Tab.UpdateDateTime,Tab.CommentInsertDate DESC OFFSET (1- 1) * 20 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

This is my sample data =>
Table Case :

```
Id | Description | InsertdateTime          | UpdateDateTime
1     feed1        2017-05-10 19:48:19.850   2017-05-11 19:48:19.850
2     feed2        2017-05-09 19:48:19.850   2017-05-10 19:48:19.850
3     feed3        2017-05-08 19:48:19.850   2017-05-19 19:48:19.850
```

Table CaseComment

```
 Id | CaseId | Comment | InsertDateTime
  1    2        test      2017-05-11 18:48:19.850
  1    2        test1     2017-05-10 17:48:19.850
  1    3        good      2017-05-09 19:48:19.850
```

My expected o/p with updates post =>

```
  Id | Description   | UpdateDateTime        | CommentInsertDateTime
  1     feed1        2017-05-11 19:48:19.850
  2     feed2        2017-05-10 19:48:19.850   2017-05-11 18:48:19.850
  3     feed3        2017-05-19 19:48:19.850   2017-05-09 19:48:19.850
```

My expected o/p with get comment on case id 3 the o/p =>

```
  Id | Description   | UpdateDateTime        | CommentInsertDateTime
   3     feed3        2017-05-19 19:48:19.850   2017-05-09 19:48:19.850
   1     feed1        2017-05-11 19:48:19.850
   2     feed2        2017-05-10 19:48:19.850   2017-05-11 18:48:19.850
```

Comment: Dou you need , when comment inserted, then first, after order by updated datetime ?

Comment: yes like i have post new feed then come as a top. then after i give the any feed comment that commented feed come at the top and one step less my new posted feed.

Comment: @SHD mean i want to first updates datetime feed and then after comment inserted first who latest feed get comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this query,

```
SELECT  C.CaseId
        ,(SELECT max(InsertDateTime) FROM CaseComment WHERE CaseId = C.CaseId)  AS  CommentInsertDateTime
        ,C.UpdateDateTime
FROM Case C   
WHERE C.IsApproved = 1
AND C.IsDeleted = 0 
ORDER BY ISNULL(CommentInsertDateTime,UpdateDateTime) DESC
```

Comment: but your query it's diff for my query so it's not possible with my query?

Comment: I think so, you only need pagination part to it, anyway run and check the result.

Comment: with  your solution come just top who case got a new comments not a come updates feed on the top can you please help me for that

Comment: Can u post, some sample data ?

Comment: see i can add my sample data as now with my data come top case id 1 and 2nd case id 2 like this i want to data

Comment: with your solution i am get case id 1 at the top but incase i can give the comment on case id 3 that time case id 3 is not come top on the tab so i want to case id 3 on the top

Comment: Post your expected output too

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get ther order u meant

Comment: i can fix it this issue with add case then in the query

Comment: i can add like this column priority_date = CASE
     WHEN Cc.InsertDateTime > C.UpdateDateTime THEN Cc.InsertDateTime
     WHEN Cc.InsertDateTime is null  THEN C.UpdateDateTime
    END  and order by priortiy_date desc

Comment: Is issue fixed ?

Comment: i can take one sp from the server and go on local and create that time i am getting this error "Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AI" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation." are you aware with this error

Comment: Sorry, I didn't, you can google or post new question here for that

Comment: Hello SHD can you please me on sql query i have post my query post number is "44364803"

Comment: Hello SHD can you please help me on this post "44623393" please

Comment: hello shd now can you see my this post "44628608" please here i want to marge data from the  table can you please help me

Comment: Hello shd can you please give me some hint

Comment: Hello shd can you please help me

Comment: sorry, Iam little busy some days, It need detailed checking, I will check it later

Comment: shahidtir@gmail.com, this is my mailid, can u send details to that?